# Javascript with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a site that is using `jquery.treeview.js` with multiple nested branches.
Each branch has a javascript button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_link" class="show_links" onclick="$(this).parent().children('div#data_316')
.load('keyword_browse_ajax.php', {keyword_id:316,lp:'et',mode:'ajax'}); $(this).parent().children('div#data_316').toggle(); $(this)
.parent().children('a#hide_link').toggle(); $(this).toggle();" style="display: none; "><img src="http://pic.gif" alt="show"></a>
```

And an "empty" div:

```
<div id="data_316" style="background: whitesmoke; display: none; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px; padding: 5px; line-height:150%;"></div>
```

That gets populated on the "show link" click:

```
<div id="data_316" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 5px; line-height: 150%;
background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
Name O.;
 <a href="link.php" target="_blank">text1</a>; 1993, nr 1, p 1-20<br>
Name T.;
 <a href="link.php" target="_blank">text2</a>; 1994, nr 1, p 1-20<br>
</div>
```

Is there a way with Selenium to unravel the tree so I can crab the newly populated div content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i am new to selenium it took some testing to get going, but it was rather simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome() # Get local session of Chrome
browser.get("http://www.somepage.com") # Load page

elem = browser.find_element_by_id("show_links") # Find javascript button
elem.click() # Click on the button that 'populates the div'
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

With the given Information In Case if we need to use Specific CSS Selector that is given below as follows

CSS Selector for Show Links:

css=#show_link > img[src*='pic.gif']

Then Perform Click on the above css using the given below method as follows

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#show_link > img[src*='pic.gif']").click()